# Black screen after purple Ubuntu screen

Tags: wubi

My friend installed ubuntu via wubi. He says when i select Ubuntu from grub menu, i see Ubuntu logo. One of the orange points turns into white and then there is empty black screen. What's wrong?

Comment: might be worth a try to add a grub boot option e.g. `nomodeset` for nvidia/ati or `i915.modeset=0` or `i915.modeset=1` for intel. i.e. press e on the grub screen and add those keywords immediately before "quiet splash"

Comment: To add to *fossfreedom*'s comment, this thread contains detailed instructions for modifying boot options on a Wubi install (first boot is different): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 (see post #8). PS post the computer brand/model/graphics card specs for more help.

Comment: We did what @fossfreedom said in the post and the problem is solved.

Comment: @serhat - I've added the comment as an answer so that you can accept the answer.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This question reads as a graphics issue on boot - possibly an incompatibility between proprietary graphics drivers and KMS - or possibly a problem with the default opensource graphics drivers.

There is not any detail in the question as to what graphics the 'friend' has in his computer, so try the following generic advice:

Add a grub boot option i.e. nomodeset for nvidia/ati or either i915.modeset=0 or  i915.modeset=1 for intel based graphics.

See this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation/38834#38834) on how to add those boot options and it also gives advice on how to fix it permanently in grub.