# Black screen after installation with wubi

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Black screen after purple Ubuntu screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55635/black-screen-after-purple-ubuntu-screen)

I tried to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu by Wubi, but after rebooting, i choose to load Ubuntu and i get a purple screen for about 5 seconds, then it turns black.